# How can I get Absolute file path at started content:// type Uri on Non-Media Type

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, filepath

The problem is that, for security reasons, we know that the absolute path of a file cannot be obtained directly from a uri starting with content://. So I solved the problem by using the library and applying it to media type files starting with content://. However, in the case of a file such as pdf that is not a media type, it is not converted properly. Is there any way I can add this to my code?

```
class UriPathUtils{
fun getRealPathFromURI(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    when {
        // DocumentProvider
        DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri) -> {
            when {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                isExternalStorageDocument(uri) -> {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "From Internal & External Storage dir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]
                    // This is for checking Main Memory
                    return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        if (split.size > 1) {
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                        } else {
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                        }
                        // This is for checking SD Card
                    } else {
                        "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/")
                    }
                }
                isDownloadsDocument(uri) -> {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "From Downloads dir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val fileName = getFilePath(context, uri)
                    if (fileName != null) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                    }
                    var id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        id = id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                        val file = File(id)
                        if (file.exists()) return id
                    }
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                }
                isMediaDocument(uri) -> {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "From Documents dir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]
                    var contentUri: Uri? = null
                    when (type) {
                        "image" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                            Log.d("image_file_contentUri", contentUri.toString())
                        }
                        "video" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        "audio" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        else -> {
                            //non-media files i.e documents and other files
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
                            Log.d("document_fil_contentUri", contentUri.toString())
                            val selection =
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?"
                            } else "_id=?"

                            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

                            Log.d("document_file_selection", selection)
                            Log.d("document_file_selArgs", selectionArgs.toString())

                            return getMediaDocumentPath(context, contentUri,selection,selectionArgs)
                        }
                    }
                    val selection = "_id=?"
                    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                    Log.d("image_file_selection", selection)
                    Log.d("image_file_selArgs", selectionArgs.toString())
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
                }
                isGoogleDriveUri(uri) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "From Google Drive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return getDriveFilePath(uri, context)
                }
            }
        }
        "content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "From Content Uri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Return the remote address
            return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        }
        "file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "From File Uri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return uri.path
        }
    }
    return null
}

private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(column)
    try {
        if (uri == null) return null
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)

        Log.d("image_file_cursor", cursor.toString())

        //여기서부터 갈림
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)

            Log.d("image_file_index", index.toString())
            Log.d("image_file_return", cursor.getString(index).toString())
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}


private fun getMediaDocumentPath(context: Context, uri: Uri?,selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(column)
    try {
        if (uri == null) return null
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)

        Log.d("document_file_cursor", cursor.toString())

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            Log.d("document_file_index", index.toString())
            Log.d("document_file_return", cursor.getString(index).toString())
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}






private fun getFilePath(context: Context, uri: Uri?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    try {
        if (uri == null) return null
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}

private fun getDriveFilePath(uri: Uri, context: Context): String? {
    val returnCursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
    val nameIndex = returnCursor!!.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
    returnCursor.moveToFirst()
    val name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
    val size = returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
    val file = File(context.cacheDir, name)
    try {
        val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        var read = 0
        val maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024
        val bytesAvailable = inputStream!!.available()

        //int bufferSize = 1024;
        val bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize)
        val buffers = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        while (inputStream.read(buffers).also { read = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
        }
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length())
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.close()
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.path)
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.message!!)
    }
    return file.path
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private fun isGoogleDriveUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage" == uri.authority || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy" == uri.authority
}
```

}

image file upload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99e2u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLKXP.png)

pdf file upload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBRjX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvjB9.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467743/how-to-get-absolute-path-from-file-uri-starting-with-content-document-type

Comment: This is your fourth question about this subject. Dont try to get a -real- path for an uri. You also dont need it for Retrofit.

Comment: `The problem is that, for security reasons, we know that the absolute path of a file cannot be obtained directly from a uri starting with content://` Not true. In many cases you can get the file system path. But also then its often useless as you have no read and write access to that path. Wasted time.